# unable to apply float in inline css ITextSharp

Tags: itext

I am trying to create report from HTML to pdf using ItextSharp.

```
var logoPath = Server.MapPath("~/Img/pricelist-logo.jpg");
var user = ApplicationService.UserRepository.GetById(Utility.GetInt(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name));
var materials = MaterialService.MaterialRepository.PriceListReportMaterials(priceListId);
var priceList = MaterialService.PriceListRepository.GetById(priceListId);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html><head></head><body>");
sb.Append("<header class='header' style=\"background: #111; height: 100px; padding: 0 20px; position: relative;\">");
sb.Append("<div class='header-container' style='width: 100%; height: 90px; padding: 0 100px; float: left;'>");
sb.Append("<div class='logo' style='float:left; align-items: center; width:50%'>");
sb.Append("<a>");
sb.Append("<img src='" + logoPath + "' style='height: 50px!important;'>");
sb.Append("</a>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("<div class='right-cnt' style='float:left; width:50%;'><h3>" + user.Organization.Title + "</h3>");
sb.Append("<p style='color:green'>"+ priceList.Title + "</p>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("</header>");
sb.Append("</body></html>");
```

As you can see, I've assigned `float:left` to `<div>`. but it doesn't work when I export HTML to pdf.

As you can see difference in PDF and actual HTML.
[image]

Comment: iText 5 (formerly known as iTextSharp) does not have full CSS support. iText 7 (latest version 7.1.16), with the pdfHTML add-on, supports a lot more CSS.

Comment: Can't add anything to what @kHLVT said! Time to switch to iText 7!